# Grouping datas in a Sqltable based on Duration

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i need to show a chatlog by sessions and the session may be splitted by the duration of 30 minutes gap between each message.

here the sample table

S.No  From      To         Message           Time

1. John      Michael    hello             12:00
2. Michael   John       hi da             12:01
3. Michael   John       are you there     12:40

here the first two message are send between 1 minute gap. but the 3rd message is send after 39 minutes so first two message is one session and 3rd message is second session. how can i split like this.

Answer (score 2):

You also tagged your question "Oracle", so here is an Oracle solution. In the next query you can see an expression with alias "GRP" that you can use to group rows that belong together:

```
SQL> select s_no
  2       , s_from
  3       , s_to
  4       , message
  5       , s_time
  6       , case
  7         when nvl(lag(s_time) over (partition by least(s_from,s_to),greatest(s_from,s_to) order by s_time,s_no),s_time)
  8           > s_time - interval '30' minute
  9         then
 10           first_value(s_time) over (partition by least(s_from,s_to),greatest(s_from,s_to) order by s_time,s_no)
 11         else
 12           s_time
 13         end grp
 14    from messages
 15   order by s_no
 16  /

      S_NO S_FROM  S_TO    MESSAGE       S_TIME              GRP
---------- ------- ------- ------------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 John    Michael hello         28-04-2011 12:00:00 28-04-2011 12:00:00
         2 Michael John    hi da         28-04-2011 12:01:00 28-04-2011 12:00:00
         3 Michael John    are you there 28-04-2011 12:40:00 28-04-2011 12:40:00
         4 Michael Alan    hi            28-04-2011 12:15:00 28-04-2011 12:15:00
         5 Alan    Michael bye           28-04-2011 12:18:00 28-04-2011 12:15:00

5 rows selected.
```

And here is an example how you can use that grouping expression to create a chatlog:

```
SQL> select min(s_no) s_no_from
  2       , max(s_no) s_no_to
  3       , least(s_from,s_to) participant1
  4       , greatest(s_from,s_to) participant2
  5       , min(s_time) time_from
  6       , max(s_time) time_to
  7    from ( select s_no
  8                , s_from
  9                , s_to
 10                , message
 11                , s_time
 12                , case
 13                  when nvl(lag(s_time) over (partition by least(s_from,s_to),greatest(s_from,s_to) order by s_time,s_no),s_time)
 14                    > s_time - interval '30' minute
 15                  then
 16                    first_value(s_time) over (partition by least(s_from,s_to),greatest(s_from,s_to) order by s_time,s_no)
 17                  else
 18                    s_time
 19                  end grp
 20             from messages
 21         )
 22   group by least(s_from,s_to)
 23       , greatest(s_from,s_to)
 24       , grp
 25   order by min(s_time)
 26  /

 S_NO_FROM    S_NO_TO PARTICI PARTICI TIME_FROM           TIME_TO
---------- ---------- ------- ------- ------------------- -------------------
         1          2 John    Michael 28-04-2011 12:00:00 28-04-2011 12:01:00
         4          5 Alan    Michael 28-04-2011 12:15:00 28-04-2011 12:18:00
         3          3 John    Michael 28-04-2011 12:40:00 28-04-2011 12:40:00

3 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

MySQL version:

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
  S_NO INT(11) NOT NULL,
  S_FROM VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  S_TO VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  MESSAGE VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  S_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (S_NO)
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES 
  (1, 'John', 'Michael', 'hello', '2011-04-28 12:00:00'),
  (2, 'Michael', 'John', 'hi da', '2011-04-28 12:01:00'),
  (3, 'Michael', 'John', 'are you there', '2011-04-28 12:40:00'),
  (4, 'Michael', 'Alan', 'hi', '2011-04-28 14:15:00'),
  (5, 'Alan', 'Michael', 'bye', '2011-04-28 14:41:00');

SET @group_number = 0;
SET @prev_time = NULL;
SET @temp_time = NULL;
SELECT group_number, s_no, s_from, s_to, message, s_time FROM (
  SELECT
    m.*,
    @temp:=@prev_time,
    @prev_time:=(SELECT MAX(S_TIME) FROM messages WHERE S_TIME < m.S_TIME) prev_time,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_time, S_TIME),
    @group_number:=CASE WHEN @prev_time IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN @temp=@prev_time OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_time, S_TIME) < 30 THEN @group_number ELSE @group_number + 1 END group_number
  FROM messages m
  ORDER BY m.S_TIME) t;

+--------------+------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| group_number | s_no | s_from  | s_to    | message       | s_time              |
+--------------+------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|            1 |    1 | John    | Michael | hello         | 2011-04-28 12:00:00 |
|            1 |    2 | Michael | John    | hi da         | 2011-04-28 12:01:00 |
|            2 |    3 | Michael | John    | are you there | 2011-04-28 12:40:00 |
|            3 |    4 | Michael | Alan    | hi            | 2011-04-28 14:15:00 |
|            3 |    5 | Alan    | Michael | bye           | 2011-04-28 14:41:00 |
+--------------+------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```